# Plugin can't be activated

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta, errors, activation

I'm developing a WordPress plugin, but the last changes caused the plugin to stop working. It tells me that I can't activate the plugin because it caused a fatal error. On localhost all is working fine, but after sending to the server, on activation it displays the following:

> Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /data/web/virtuals/72282/virtual/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-songbook/inc/wpsongs-shortcs.php
>   on line 83

I really don't understand the context of this message, because the code of this line is:

```
$ytlink=(isset(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'songbook_video_link')))?get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'songbook_video_link'):false;
```

Can anyone tell me what's happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) expects a variable to be passed to it. Also, I'm assuming that you expect the [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to return a scalar value and not an array, so I added the third parameter set to true.

```
// 3rd param: $single. Value of true means get scalar value, not an array.    
$ytlink = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'songbook_video_link', true );

// Will ensure that $ytlink is boolean false, and not an empty string.
$ytlink = ( ! empty( $ytlink ) ) ? $ytlink : false;
```

Comment: Sorry, Ive tried to use your code, and got this message (only on domain):
`The plugin generated 573 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.`

Comment: No Problem. That code snippet does not generate any output, so it's not the culprit. Can you please post your code?

Comment: I explored, that the trouble was by wrong activation hook function, that returned something... Thank you for help :)